# Get rendered HTML contents of Vue slot as variable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I know you can do something like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="title is-1" v-html="text"></h1>
    <get-slot-contents>
      <p>Hi there</p>
      <p>Hi <span>heloo</span></p>
      <p>Hi there</p>
      <p>Hi there</p>
    </get-slot-contents>
  </div>
</div>

// JS

Vue.component('get-slot-contents', {
  data: function () {
    return {
      html : false
    }
  },
  template: `<div>
    ****
    <slot></slot>
    ****
  </div>`,
  mounted(){
    console.log(this.$slots.default);
  }
});
```

This logs the following:

```
[fo, fo, fo, fo, fo, fo, fo]
```

Each `fo` containing something like:

```
{tag: undefined, data: undefined, children: undefined, text: " ", elm: text, …}
```

How would I `console.log` something like:

```
<p>Hi there</p><p>Hi <span>heloo</span></p><p>Hi there</p><p>Hi there</p>
```

For the purposes of this you can assume there are no nested components.

Comment: They all go into a single `<slot>`, which is the default slot. You can't tease them apart, unless you traverse the markup of the slot to read each node.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would getting `innerHTML` from `this.$el` works for you?

demo: https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/vjmzWg?editors=1010

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="title is-1"></h1>
    <get-slot-contents>
      <p>Hi there</p>
      <p>Hi <span>heloo</span></p>
      <p>Hi there</p>
      <p>Hi there</p>
    </get-slot-contents>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
Vue.component("get-slot-contents", {
  data: function() {
    return {
      html: false
    };
  },
  template: `<div>
    ****
    <div class="slot-wrapper">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
    ****
  </div>`,
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$el.getElementsByClassName("slot-wrapper")[0].innerHTML);
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
});
```

Comment: Ah yeah... that was simple enough! Thanks :)

Comment: Simpler and more stable: Put `ref="slotWrapper"` on the element and use `this.$refs.slotWrapper.innerHTML`.